# 2 parallel planes, the front one is rotated, when view is rotated, portions of the plane on the back is visible through the plane on the front

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

Any idea why the purple plane is showing through? These planes are parallel. Using Eevee. If I create this topology fresh I don't see the issue. But in this particular blender file, I somehow arrived at this problem and I don't remember what all I was trying. Which setting may be causing it?

[image: parallel planes]

[good file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14R96oJlIBBocwjZ5S3mb-j_D0YU_U6Ez/view?usp=sharing)

[bad file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WivUNbODt3evP7f227MV2dXsserBm4R_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: purple plane's z = 0.0 m, red plane's z = 0.006 m. However, strange part if that I created exact same topology in a new file and there I don't see this issue at all. Is there any setting I might have done accidentally to cause this? The blend mode is set to "opaque". I also observe that blend mode "alpha blend", fixes it. But "opaque" should also work.

Comment: good file and bad file have the same topology. good file doesn't have that problem, but bad file has. And it only happens when view is rotated.

Comment: Some Eevee issues of that kind can be solved reducing the camera view clip start and end to the minimum required in the scene.

Answer (score 1):

This is called z-fighting, and it's caused by blender not being able to properly decide which one to draw in front of the other.  You need some difference in the z coordinate, and if it's not large enough this can still happen at great distances due to floating point precision funkiness.